# How to Switch between channels (brand Account) on Android

Tags: android, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am doing an Android app that integrates the [Youtube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started).

In Google's ["Try this API" tool](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list), it is possible to pick the brand account you want to interact with (a prompt will show up right after you pick your Google account).

However, I am not able to have the same behaviour in my app. I am successfully getting an OAuth token by using the [Google Sign-In for Android API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)
, but I don't know how to get a prompt to pick a brand account. I can only manage my "main" account.

Is it something that is possible to achieve in Android?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can see OAuth 2.0 Flow: Devices docs https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/guides/auth/devices

Load url(http://www.google.com/device) into webview.

and Begin polling until the login process is complete.

Then access_token is obtained and completed.